# Background service that's constantly running once it's called in Blazor Server project?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

is there a way to add a background service that once it's triggered/called it runs until it's finished? Example:

I need to iterate through huge database (which takes quite some time), find the information and store it in other database. That service will be triggered on one of the Razor pages and I want to browse other pages while that service is running without stopping it.

I tried creating service, such as default WeatherForecastService, and defined it in Startup.cs, but service stops once I leave the page on which it was called.

Comment: See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would run this in another service like an Azure Function app.

But to keep it simple, create a Service class and register it as Singleton.
Its main method would look like:

```
public void DoWork()
{
   Task.Run(DoActualWork); // ignore "not awaited" warning
}

public bool IsBusy { get; private set; }

private async Task DoActualWork()
{
   lock(this)
   {
     if (IsBusy) return;
     IsBusy = true;
   }
   
   // use a try/catch
   // set up a Scope for DI

   IsBusy = false;
}
```

Read about creating a Scope [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface) for instance.

You can use properties to manage and monitor but do make that thead-safe.

Note that any finally's in DoWork are not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component which injects the service and place it in the `MainLayout.razor` file.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
    <MyBackgroundService/>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```